# What is this string-literal in boolean expression idiom?

Tags: c++, c

A coworker of mine was looking through one of our inherited code bases and found the following line:

`ATLASSERT( rtaddress == m_lRTAddress && "Creation settings should match FIFO" );`

We don't understand what the purpose of the string literal is for; is it for more than just commenting?  The way I see it, if `rtaddress` does NOT equal `m_lRTAddress` then the string will never be evaluated due to short circuiting. If `rtaddress` DOES equal `m_lRTAddress` then the string literal will be evaluated but a string literal evaluated for a boolean expression will always return `true`; so what's the point?

Comment: It is a trick to get that string to appear in the assert dialog.  Self-documenting warning message.

Comment: It is a reprehensible waste of space and is obscurantism too. Use a comment. The assertion failure message will direct you to the source code line (at least it will if an ATLASSERT is like a standard assert).

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I think it's so that if the assert fails you can see the reason why the assert was added.